# xmlstarlet delete parent elements from multiple documents recursively

Tags: xml, recursion, xpath, xmlstarlet

Have a set of xml docs in separate directories, each document like this:

```
    <xmldoc>
      <data>data text</data>
      <parent>
        <descendent1>
          <descendent2>motorcyclebaby.com?query</descendent2>
        </descendent1>
      </parent>
    </xmldoc>
```

I want to remove the parent element that contains "motorcycle" in descendent2 in all of the documents. So far, I have this, which works for a single doc:

```
   xmlstarlet ed -d "//parent[descendent1/descendent2[contains(text(),'motorcycle')]]" xmldoc.xml
```

I've tried this to delete the parent element recursively with find:

```
    find . -name 'xmldoc.xml' -print0 | xmlstarlet ed -d "//parent[descendent1/descendent2[contains(text(),'motorcycle')]]" xmldoc.xml
```

but got 'failed to load external entity "xmldoc.xml"'

also tried:

```
    find . -name "xmldoc.xml" -exec xmlstarlet ed -d "//parent[descendent1/descendent2[contains(text(),'motorcycle')]]" xmldoc.xml {} +
```

Comment: The line that worked in a single doc might not have worked. Had to add --inplace: xmlstarlet ed --inplace -d "//parent[descendent1/descendent2[contains(text(),'motorcycle')]]" xmldoc.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out!

```
    find . -iname "xmldoc.xml" -exec xmlstarlet ed --inplace -d "//parent[descendent1/descendent2[contains(text(),'motorcycle')]]" {} +
```

-iname to ignore case since my docs were capitalized

//parent[descendent1/descendent2[contains... needed to select the entire parent element where the child contained the searched string.

--inplace needed to make changes to the actual documents, rather than printed in Terminal.

{} + needed with -exec to make the change to each document listed by find.

\o/

Comment: You shouldn't need the `xmldoc.xml` at the end again, the `{}` goes instead of it. Otherwise you are re-editing the doc in the current directory once again per every other file (harmless for this particular edit, but not in general).

Comment: @shellter Kind of a non-issue since once the element is deleted, the command can't do anything. But removed per your advice. (to new readers: it said `find . -iname "xmldoc.xml" -exec xmlstarlet ed --inplace -d "//parent[descendent1/descendent2[contains(text(),'motorcycle')]]" xmldoc.xml {} +`)